# Minus Parameter in expression of report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this expression into my report

```
=Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value(0)
```

When I execute report it returns:

```
[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].&[2016]
```

I want to minus 1 to 2016 so I just do:

```
=Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value(0) -1
```

But it throws me an error and it just don´t specify why, can someone help me how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: please post the error

Comment: it just throw label #Error, but log don´t specified why error occurs. I posted an image of it @YanetPedraza

Comment: Looks like your parameter Dimtiempoanio is multi valued.. is that correct? and it is a string? If you try to substract 1 from a string, it will return an error..

Comment: try casting the value (to int) before applying any arithmetic operations

Comment: Yes is multi valued, how can I achieve that I want? @Harry

Comment: I try to cast it using  `=INT(Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value(0)) - 1` but same problem @Sparrow

Comment: you are trying to display a parameter in a label/ text box.. correct?.. so what happens if you have more than one parameter selected? I mean, do you subtract -1 from each of the parameter selected? what is the desired result then?

Comment: @sparrow you cant just cast the whole thing as INT.. it has characters.. casting it as an int is still a string.. hence you end up with the same error!

Comment: Yes it´s correct, I validate my select to user can only select 1 value at time.. How can I substract it into an expression? Desire result is get: 2015 when Dim_tiempo equals to `[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].&[2016]` @Harry

Comment: There is any way to solve this issue? @Harry

Comment: @Pepe see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In not entirely convinced that this is the best way to do it.. but here is one that might work

```
=replace(Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value,right(Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value,5),(cstr(cint(left(right(Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value, 5),4)) -1)))+"]"
```

Comment: I change it for a little more easy like: `=CINT(Left(Right(Parameters!DimTiempoAnio.Value(0),5),4)) -1` it works

Comment: yeah.. but you wanted the whole parameter displayed with the lesser year in your original question.. your's just results in 2014 being displayed in the box.. not what you originally asked for!